# Running commands from fiij menu in java code

Tags: netbeans, imagej

I need to run a command from fiji menu in java code developed using netbeans IDE. The command is Image--Color--RGB to CIELAB.

I used "IJ.run" to run commands from ImageJ menu like Fill Holes(i.e. IJ.run(imp,"Fill Holes","")). But I don't know how to do this using fiji.

When I use IJ.run(imp,"RGB to CIELAB","");

I got the following error:

Unrecognized command: "RGB to CIELAB"

Any help to run commands from fiji menu in java code?

Comment: I guess it was you who asked [the same question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/fiji-devel/running$20commands/fiji-devel/swn23-uQNUI/xvvSRc845CgJ) on the fiji-devel mailing list two weeks ago? The issue has been extensively discussed there, so in case you couldn't solve it yet, I suggest that you continue that thread providing more information. Opening a new question without even linking to the context where it was discussed before means wasting the time of people willing to help. Did you make sure the the `plugins.dir` property has been set correctly for `IJ.run` to work?

Comment: Yes I did. But Actually I am still having the problem! 
I have used 

System.getProperties().setProperty("plugins.dir", "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\fiji-win64\\Fiji.app\\plugins");

to set plugins.dir but this did not work

Answer (score 0):

To get the Java command to convert RGB to CIELAB, do the following within a running Fiji instance:

- Invoke the command finder using *Plugins > Utilities > Find commands...* or by typing *Ctrl-L* (*Cmd-L* on Mac OSX)
- In the search field, type *CIELAB*: this will show you that the command *RGB to CIELAB* runs an instance of the class `RGB_to_CIELAB`
- Now start the script editor using *File > New > Script* or by typing *\*
- Run *Tools > Open .java file for class...* and type **RGB_to_CIELAB**

This will open the file [`RGB_to_CIELAB.java`](http://fiji.sc/RGB_to_CIELAB.java). Observing the code, you will see that it creates a new `ImagePlus` and invokes its `show()` method, something you probably want to avoid when calling the class from java code outside a Fiji instance. Unless the original code is changed to *return* an `ImagePlus` instead of *showing* it in the GUI (you are welcome to submit a pull request to https://github.com/fiji/fiji/), you might better directly use one of the utility methods in the [`CIELAB`](http://fiji.sc/CIELAB.java) class (see [javadoc](http://fiji.sc/javadoc/index.html?color/CIELAB.html)), e.g.:

```
CIELAB.CIELAB2sRGB(float[] lab, float[] rgb)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for help. Actually I have solved it using the following command: IJ.runPlugIn(imp_lab,"RGBtoLab_", "");